# foward the value of datetimepicker in other form to display it in the textbox

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, button

How can i foward the value of datetimepicker named dtpDAILY when clicking the ok button and form named DAIILY

[image]

and to display it in other form named SALES and put it in a textbox named txtSUMMARY ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

First get the open form which is Sales using Application.OpenForms, then set the txtSummary.Text on the value you get from DateTimePicker:

```
SalesForm frmSales = Application.OpenForms.OfType<SalesForm>().SingleOrDefault();
frmSales.txtSUMMARY.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToLongDateString();
frmSales.Show();
this.Close();
```

Make sure you set your txtSummary textbox to public on its Access Modifier properties:

[image]